# How to style table <td> content all as same size

Tags: php, loops, html-table

I have PHP script which has nested loops. One first loop get's the data and second loop which checks the data and if quantity is more than 1; it loops through and display each order separately. All works fine.

I'm having some styling issues.
One of my  is inside loop.

```
  for($i=0; $i < $row['numberassigned_vnr']; $i++){ 
        ?>

 <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <?php
        for($x=0; $x < $row['noof10s_vnr']; $x++){ 
            ?>

            <td><img alt="" class="yellow-process center-block " id ="cut-full-roll-<?php echo $row['id_vnr']; ?>" name="<?php echo $row['id_vnr']; ?>" src="../../css/icons/vinyl-rolls/cut.png"></td>
        <?php
        }
        ?>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

[image]

The number of my second can be anything from 1 to 6. And the "cut" picture will be displayed according to the number of quantity. If quantity, 3 picture will be displayed in a row.

My question is how i can keep the image size same. At the moment the more qunatity loop has the smaller the image become. I would like to keep all images same.

How I can achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: Please remember to mark an answer as selected if one fixes your problem

Answer (score 0):

Set the `<img>` height and width to fixed values.

Comment: I applied height and width to the <td>. it made the the <td> as same size but the actual images within the <td> are still different and the size depends on the number of pictures in the row.

Comment: No, you want to set the height and width of the `<img>` to be constant if you want them to all be the same size.  The `<td>`s in a row will grow to fill the row, so if you make the images the same size as the `<td>` it will grow when there are fewer cells in a row.

Comment: I have tried that. I given the image a class and set a width for that class. But they still appear different sizes.

Comment: Edit your post to show the CSS for your `<img>` class

Comment: .yellow-process {
  width: 30%;
 }

Comment: `30%` is not a fixed width.  You need to set it to a specific size, e.g. `30px`  When you say `30%` you're saying "take the table cell size and make the image 30% of that" - and since the table cell size changes depending on the quantity, the image size will change as well.

Comment: awww I understand you now @FKinterent. I was using % sign instead of px. Thank you soo much to all for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you had not given any specific width or height or something like that in class table or table-bordered

Then specify stylings to the td eg.

```
td {
    min-width :256px;   1/6th of Screen size
    ......
}
```

Hope it helps

Let me know if you require any further help

Comment: That didn't work. The height and width got applied to table td column, But the pictures were still different sizes. The first row has 6 picture so they are smaller to second and third row because they contain 4 pictures. I would like the image size to be same never-mind the row contains 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 6 images. 6 will be the max number of images.

Comment: Had you used any stylings that includes width or height or something related

Comment: I given class to image and styled width to 35%. other than that; I have not used any styling to table or rows.

Comment: Once try updated answer and remove that width from img

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using CSS.

```
td {
    width: *px*|*%*;
    height: *px*|*%*;
}
```

Or the same to images.

```
img {
    width: *px*|*%*;
    height: *px*|*%*;
}
```

If you realy want all the images to be of the same size irrespective of their number in the row, then give fixed sizes to your images as I suggested in the second option above.

Don't use % for height and width, use px instead as you need fixed size irrespective of row width.

Comment: Did you try using px instead of % ?